# Give Wordpress custom page template a title for appearance editor

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

When in Wordpress theme appearance editor, certain pages have a neat titles displayed in the right hand list for your theme files.For example page.php shows as "Page Template". This is clean and easily read.

Is there any comment syntax that Wordpress uses to give these titles for my custom page template?

For example, my single-video.php page could be "Video Page Template".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Make sure your page opens with something like:

```
<?php /** Template Name: Text & Image 
*/ get_header(); ?>
```

In this case the name of the file in your file overview (while in your appearance editor): Text & Image Page Template

Comment: This worked.This is the correct answer. I currently do not have enough reputation to  up vote this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! You can mark this answer as the right answer i think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The reason being that `single-{type}` pages are not essentially a required part of WordPress Template files, where as `page.php` is as it is used to for all static WordPress pages.

So it makes sense that WordPress people set a neat title for `page.php` and left `single-{type}` pages unattended. Also, type of `single-{type}` pages are user defined and subject to variation; where as `page.php` templates are not.

You may refer [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist) from WordPress Codex for more information

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you need to provide a proper formatted URL `(permalink)` to wordpress  Like either you want a `dash (-)` OR  `Forward Slash (/)` OR whatever you want.

For this Go to `Admin Panel > Appearance  > Permalinks` , here you can see the different styles of permalinks.You can create your own `permalink structure` too.

Find the attachment for your help.

[image]