# How to edit appearance list title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, css

Please help me i want to change wordpress admin appearance list title please see attached screenshot
[image: Please see pointed area which i want to edit i want to change title]

Comment: I want to change The title of list.

Comment: It is related to theme. What is your theme name?

Comment: [How to edit appearance list title in wordpress - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809404/give-wordpress-custom-page-template-a-title-for-appearnce-editor)

Comment: It is Onetone Theme "Onetone Options" which i want to change like ABC Options

Comment: I think you should at the very least, explain what the picture is showing in text form.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code will give you "ABC Options".

Go to `wp-content/themes/onetone/includes/theme-setup.php`.

In this file change the below function.

```
function onetone_optionscheck_options_menu_params( $menu ) {

    $menu['page_title'] = __( 'Onetone Options', 'onetone');
    $menu['menu_title'] = __( 'Onetone Options', 'onetone');
    $menu['menu_slug'] = 'onetone-options';
    return $menu;
}
```

to

```
function onetone_optionscheck_options_menu_params( $menu ) {

    $menu['page_title'] = __( 'ABC Options', 'onetone');
    $menu['menu_title'] = __( 'ABC Options', 'onetone');
    $menu['menu_slug'] = 'onetone-options';
    return $menu;
}
```

I have tested in my localhost. It is working fine.

See the below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Bear in mind, this will need re-creating if ever the theme files are updated.

Comment: @Lee We can do it in our child theme. Then no need to worry about theme update.

Comment: If it is useful, Kindly upvote it or accept as answer.